# Wordpress - is get_posts() more efficient than The Loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, wordpress-theming

In `category.php`, I want to get list of posts in that category.

I found two ways: using `get_posts($args)` and `The Loop`.

**get_posts()** way

```
$args = array (
  "category" => ID );
$posts = get_posts($args);
// then use foreach to loop the $posts
```

**The Loop** way

```
<?php if (have_posts() ): ?>
  <?php while (have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
    ...
  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**So which one is more efficient?**

From what I have found in searching, `get_posts()` is for custom templates while `The Loop` is used inside the template that follows the Wordpress naming convention.

I prefer `get_posts()`, but if there's a big overhead compared to The Loop, I should re-think it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer.

When we open a page using the right template (template that follows the naming convention), Wordpress automatically do query to get all the relevant posts or content

So if I use `$posts = get_posts($args);`, it means I do additional query which is unnecessary.

`$posts = get_posts($args);` should only be used outside template for example on **sidebar** that always be there on every pages.